approximate square roots of fractions with rationals
How to compute the rational approximation of square root of a fraction, i.e. I'd like to find $ \frac{a}{b} \approx \sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}$, where $a$, $b$, $m$ and $n$ are integers.
Ideally, the approximation should only use additions, subtractions and multiplications.
Thanks.

yes.... there is a way to calculate continued fraction for your $\sqrt {m/n}.$   that uses only integer operations.

@WillJagy Could you please elaborate or give some references? Thanks.

my favorite is Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/indefinite_binary_Buell.pdf

Using Newton's iterations you may find excellent approximations by iterating :
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} & = n \, a_n^2+m \, b_n^2 \\
b_{n+1} & = 2\,n\,a_n\, b_n \\
\end{align}
Example for $m=17$ and $n=3$ and starting with $a_0=2,b_0=1$ I get :
\begin{align}
2 &/ 1 \\
29 &/ 12 \\
4971 &/ 2088 \\
148248171 &/ 62276688 \\
131865120374774571 &/ 55394430551625888 \\
\end{align}
(the last fraction gives $ 2.380476142847616715$ that we may compare with the actual $2.38047614284761666\cdots$)

Too bad reducing fractions is not allowed

Thanks for the answer, and it works great for small $m$ and $n$. However, $m$ and $n$ are quite large in my case, and there is integer overflow even at the first iteration. So I'm wondering how to approximate $m/n$ with $c/d$, where $c$ and $d$ are small numbers. Or are there other ways to find $a/b$? Thanks.

Well Newton’s method will double the resulting precision at each iteration but at the price of (more than) double the size of the $a_n,,b_n$. Using Newton's method for large $m$ or $n$ may require integer division using $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+\lfloor (m,b_n^2 +n/2)/n\rfloor,;b_{n+1}=2,a_n,b_n$ (if your cpu allows integer division you should have the equivalent of Muldiv : the intermediate product using two registers before the division). Without division you'll have to use another of the methods proposed...

"may require integer division" or at least a practical method to evaluate the nearest integer to the product $b_k^2 \left(\frac mn\right)$ in $a_{k+1}=a_k^2+[b_k^2 \frac mn]$

The method shown is due to Gauss and Lagrange.  At the beginning, we need the floor of the square root of the disciminant. For the first example $\left\lfloor \sqrt{4 \cdot 23 \cdot 6} \right\rfloor  = 23$ For the second example $\left\lfloor \sqrt{4 \cdot 61 \cdot 11} \right\rfloor  = 51.$  We can accomplish this with Newton's method restricted to integers.
Examples from the program I already have....  the continued fraction of a quadratic irrational may have an initial segment, then pure cyclic begins.
CF for $$ \sqrt{\frac{23}{6}}  $$
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle  23 0 -6

  0  form             23           0          -6  delta     -1
  1  form             -6          12          17


           0          -1
           1          -1

To Return  
          -1           1
          -1           0

0  form   -6 12 17   delta  1     ambiguous  
1  form   17 22 -1   delta  -22
2  form   -1 22 17   delta  1     ambiguous  
3  form   17 12 -6   delta  -2
4  form   -6 12 17


  form   -6 x^2  + 12 x y  17 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = -1   y = 1 disc 552 dSqrt 23  M_Ratio  14.69444
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
23  -68
-24  71
=========================================

The numbers I like to call "digits"  are  the absolute values of the "deltas" so
$$  1; \color{red}{ 1, 22, 1, 2, } \color{blue}{ 1, 22, 1, 2, } ... $$
The sequence of convergents begins
$$   \frac{1}{1}, \; \;   \frac{2}{1}, \; \;   \frac{45}{23}, \; \; 
 \frac{47}{24}, \; \;  \frac{139}{71}, \; \;  \frac{186}{95}, \; \; 
   \frac{4231}{2161}, \; \; \frac{4417}{2256}, \; \;
  \frac{13065}{6673}, \; \; \frac{17482}{8929}, \; \;
   $$
The convergents just before the 22 kicks in are the most accurate as a function of the denominator. $2/1=2$ $186/95 \approx 1.9578947$  while the actual square root is $ \approx 1.957890021.$  Next cycle, $17482/8929 \approx 1.957890021$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
Next example, longer cycle. $\sqrt{\frac{61}{11}} \approx 2.354878881 $
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle  61 0 -11

  0  form             61           0         -11  delta     -2
  1  form            -11          44          17


           0          -1
           1          -2

To Return  
          -2           1
          -1           0

0  form   -11 44 17   delta  2     ambiguous  
1  form   17 24 -31   delta  -1
2  form   -31 38 10   delta  4
3  form   10 42 -23   delta  -2
4  form   -23 50 2   delta  25
5  form   2 50 -23   delta  -2     ambiguous  
6  form   -23 42 10   delta  4
7  form   10 38 -31   delta  -1
8  form   -31 24 17   delta  2
9  form   17 44 -11   delta  -4
10  form   -11 44 17


  form   -11 x^2  + 44 x y  17 y^2 

minimum was   2rep   x = -11   y = 31 disc 2684 dSqrt 51  M_Ratio  21.49587
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-8834  38471
24893  -108406
=========================================

$$  2; \color{red}{ 2, 1, 4, 2, 25, 2, 4, 1, 2,4, \; } \color{blue}{2, 1, 4, 2, 25, 2, 4, 1, 2,4, \; } ... $$
$$   \frac{2}{1}, \; \;   \frac{5}{2}, \; \;   \frac{7}{3}, \; \; 
 \frac{33}{14}, \; \;  \frac{73}{31}, \; \;  \frac{1858}{789}, \; \; 
  $$
and on and on
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

"However, m and n are quite large in my case, and there is integer overflow even at the first iteration. So I'm wondering how to approximate m/n with c/d, where c and d
are small numbers."
First, calculate the continued fraction for m/n. If you are not familiar with this, I suggest the section "Using Euclid's GCD algorithm to make a continued fraction" here: https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/cfINTRO.html
The continued fraction, calculated term by term, will yield successive 'best' approximations to m/n.  They are 'best' approximations in the sense that, for a given denominator d, there is no fraction that is both closer to m/n and has a smaller denominator than d.  The reasons why this is so are also discussed on the page linked above.
Example:
m = 180769821953
n = 232919913290
The continued fraction for m/n is: [0;1,3,2,6,1,12,1,1,1,3,2,1,2,6,5,14,1,1,2,12,88]
Truncating the continued fraction to [0;1,3,2,6,1,12,1,1,1,3] yields c = 7723, d = 9951. The approximation error is less than four parts in a billion but there are now four digits instead of twelve in numerator and denominator. Truncating further will reduce the size of numerator and denominator but will increase the error.
I think that answers the quoted question.
However, I do not think it is the best approach to the original problem, because it introduces two stages of approximation. I think Will Jagy's suggestion above is neatest, because it will generate convergence to the square root of m/n rather than to m/n. I suggest looking at the website I linked above, on the subject of periodic continued fractions for square roots.

We can compute the continued fraction of $\sqrt{\frac{23}6}$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
n&&r_n&=\frac1{r_{n-1}-\lfloor r_{n-1}\rfloor}&\lfloor r_n\rfloor\\[6pt]
\hline
0&&\sqrt{\frac{23}6}&=\frac{\sqrt{138}}6&1\\
1&&\frac6{\sqrt{138}-6}&=\frac{\sqrt{138}+6}{17}&1\\
2&&\frac{17}{\sqrt{138}-11}&=\sqrt{138}+11&22\\
3&&\frac1{\sqrt{138}-11}&=\frac{\sqrt{138}+11}{17}&1\\
4&&\frac{17}{\sqrt{138}-6}&=\frac{\sqrt{138}+6}6&2\\
5&&\frac6{\sqrt{138}-6}&=\frac{\sqrt{138}+6}{17}&1
\end{align}\tag1
$$
Since $r_5=r_1$, we get the recurrent continued fraction
$$
\sqrt{\frac{23}6}=1;\overline{1,22,1,2}\tag2
$$
The convergents of the continued fraction in $(2)$ have numerators and denominators that follow the recursions in $(3)$.
$$
\begin{align}
a_{4n+2}&=22a_{4n+1}+a_{4n}\tag{3a}\\
a_{4n+3}&=a_{4n+2}+a_{4n+1}\tag{3b}\\
a_{4n+4}&=2a_{4n+3}+a_{4n+2}\tag{3c}\\
a_{4n+5}&=a_{4n+4}+a_{4n+3}\tag{3d}\\
\hline
a_{4n+3}&=23a_{4n+1}+a_{4n}\tag{4a}\\
a_{4n+4}&=3a_{4n+3}-a_{4n+1}\tag{4b}\\
\hline
a_{4n+3}&=24a_{4n+1}-a_{4n-1}\tag{5a}\\
a_{4n+5}&=4a_{4n+3}-a_{4n+1}\tag{5b}\\
\hline
a_{4n+5}&=94a_{4n+1}-a_{4n-3}\tag{6a}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3):}$ the recurrences induced by $(2)$
$\text{(4a):}$ cancel $a_{4n+2}$ in $\text{(3a)}$ and $\text{(3b)}$
$\text{(4b):}$ cancel $a_{4n+2}$ in $\text{(3b)}$ and $\text{(3c)}$
$\text{(5a):}$ cancel $a_{4n}$ in $\text{(3d)}$ and $\text{(4a)}$
$\text{(5b):}$ cancel $a_{4n}$ in $\text{(3d)}$ and $\text{(4b)}$
$\text{(6a):}$ cancel $a_{4n+3}$ in $\text{(5a)}$ and $\text{(5b)}$
The convergents of the continued fraction can be constructed using $(3)$. The numerators and denominators that get multiplied by $22$, that is, those whose indices are $1\pmod4$, are highlighted in red
$$
\begin{array}{r}
n&&&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
&&&1&1&22&1&2&1&22&1&2&1\\\hline 
p&0&1&1&\color{#C00}{2}&45&47&139&\color{#C00}{186}&4231&4417&13065&\color{#C00}{17482}\\
q&1&0&1&\color{#C00}{1}&23&24&71&\color{#C00}{95}&2161&2256&6673&\color{#C00}{8929}
\end{array}\tag7
$$
Note that those convergents follow the recursion in $\text{(6a)}$:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
p&2&186&17482\\
q&1&95&8929
\end{array}\tag8
$$
Because the next term of the continued fraction for each of the convergents in $(8)$ is $22$, we get the approximation
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac pq-\sqrt{\frac{23}6}\right|&\le\frac1{22q^2}\tag{9a}\\
\left|6p^2-23q^2\right|&\le\frac{24}{22}\tag{9b}\\[6pt]
6p^2-23q^2&=1\tag{9c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(9a):}$ approximation due to the recurrence in $\text{(3a)}$
$\text{(9b):}$ multiply by $\frac pq+\sqrt{\frac{23}6}\lt4$, then multiply by $6q^2$
$\text{(9c):}$ $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\text{(9b)}$ says that $6p^2-23q^2\in\{-1,0,1\}$
$\phantom{\text{(9c):}}$ the odd convergents are overestimates
Extending $(8)$ with the recurrence
$$
a_n=94a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\tag{10}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{array}{r}
n&0&1&2&3&4&5\\
p&2&2&186&17482&1643122&154435986\\
q&-1&1&95&8929&839231&78878785
\end{array}\tag{11}
$$
Due to $\text{(9a)}$ and Legendre's Theorem on Continued Fractions, the rational approximations in $(11)$, extended by $(10)$, are the only ones that satisfy $\text{(9c)}$.

To get the best rational approximation, given an upper limit for the denominator, to any number, you use continued fractions.
What kind of number you approximate doesn’t matter much, except rational numbers have finite continued fractions, and if you start with any number of the form $p/q +/- \sqrt {n/m}$ which is between k and k + 1, and write it as k + 1/k’, then k’ is a number of the same form. (Try any example fraction to see how this works).
Example: Let x = $4/3 + \sqrt{3/2}$. x is between 2 and 3, so x = k + 1/k’ with k = 2 and k’ = 1 / (x-2).
x - 2 = $\sqrt{3/2} - 2/3$ = $(3/2 -4/9) / (\sqrt{3/2} + 2/3)$ = $(19/18) / (\sqrt{3/2} + 2/3)$.
k’ = $(\sqrt{3/2} + 2/3) \cdot 18 / 19$ = $\sqrt{(3 \cdot 18^2) / (2 \cdot 19^2) + 36/57$.

Could you please give an example of using continued fractions to compute rational approximations of square roots of fractions?

That answer doesn't help the OP find a good approximation. Also your vague second paragraph contradicts your more your less correct first paragraph ("doesn't matter much" - duh?).

I’m editing , patience.
